# CSS issue styling nav tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make navigation bar. I am applying padding around nav iteams but it is falling out of its parent  nav tag. How to deal with this kind of problem. Thanks

HTML

```
<header>
        <div class="wrap">
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"></a>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">My Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">My Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) { 

    * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .logo {
        display: block;
    }
    nav {
        background-color: aliceblue;
        float: none;
        display: block; 
    }
    nav li {
        /* padding: 5px; */
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a { 
      background-color: #999;
        padding: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    nav ul {
    width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for you and others to use: http://jsfiddle.net/bL2vxq2q/  Please create these yourself in future - sure fire way of getting help quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add display block to anchor tag

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lzgtugm/)

```
nav li a { 
      background-color: #999;
        padding: 30px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) { 

    * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .logo {
        display: block;
    }
    nav {
        background-color: aliceblue;
        float: none;
        display: block; 
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    nav li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
    }
    nav li a { 
      background-color: #999;
        padding: 30px;
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul {
      width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="wrap">
        <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="logo.jpg"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">My Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">My Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">My Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">My Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```